# EKS Nodes behind an ELB is OutOfService

Tags: amazon-web-services, tcp, kubernetes, amazon-elb, amazon-eks

Have an EKS Cluster that has an ELB along with 3 worker nodes attached to it. The application is running within the container on 30590. Have configured health check on the same port 30590. Kube-proxy is listening to this port. But the worker nodes are OutOfService behind the ELB.

1. Disabled Source, destination check for the Worker nodes.
2. diabled the rp_filter by "echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/{all,eth0,eth1,eth2}/rp_filter"
3. Output of 'sudo iptables -vL':

```
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
13884  826K KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW /* kubernetes externally-visible service portals */
2545K 1268M KUBE-FIREWALL  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 92 packets, 28670 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1307K  409M KUBE-FORWARD  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             /* kubernetes forwarding rules */
1301K  409M DOCKER-USER  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 139 packets, 12822 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 349K   21M KUBE-SERVICES  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW /* kubernetes service portals */
2443K  222M KUBE-FIREWALL  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1301K  409M RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain KUBE-FIREWALL (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             /* kubernetes firewall for dropping marked packets */ mark match 0x8000/0x8000

Chain KUBE-FORWARD (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    3   180 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             /* kubernetes forwarding rules */ mark match 0x4000/0x4000

Chain KUBE-SERVICES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

4. Output of : sudo tcpdump -i eth0 port 30590

```
12:41:44.217236 IP ip-192-168-186-107.ec2.internal.22580 > ip-x-x-x-.ec2.internal.30590: Flags [S], seq 3790958206, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 10236779 ecr 0,nop,wscale 8], length 0
12:41:44.217834 IP ip-x-x-x-.ec2.internal.30590 > ip-192-168-186-107.ec2.internal.22580: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 3790958207, win 0, length 0
```

Looks like the EKS nodes are sending TCP RSTs to the ELB as this is why they are failing the ELB healthchecks.
Can anyone help me in troubleshooting the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution :)
The issue was with the replicationcontroller.json file, that I had mentioned a wrong port to be exposed, & trying to connect on a different port.